# Raspberry Pi 3 as relay command not found

Tags: raspberry-pi

I installed tor on my rasberry pi-3. the processor is armhf. All installed without complaint.
I followd the below link to do the setup.

https://www.linux.com/news/turn-your-raspberry-pi-tor-relay-node

Going to root and typing tor, I get command not found. Using systemctl start tor.service produces the same result. Entering tor --verify-config produces command not found.

OS is Raspbian

Any Ideas?? Totally lost

Adriann

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian is just another flavor of Debian for Raspberry Pi. If `/usr/sbin/tor` is not available, then Tor is not installed.

You can confirm the status of Tor by running:

```
sudo apt info tor
```

You should see a line that says, "APT-Manual-Installed: yes"

If it is not installed, then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install tor
```

Finally, you should never run tor as root. Always run it as a normal user whenever possible.

Comment: Wow! thanks :-) I will give that a try.!
Re: root. I know that. The object is to get the relay running first, THEN deal with the root issue. To quote Arnold Schwarzenegger "I'll be back" :-)

Comment: following your direction (as root) apt info tor Resp: E: Invalid operation info. Cutting to the chase - /usr/sbin/ search for tor - not found. sudo apt && etc.. produced: Depends libssl1.0.0 but is not installable; Recommends: tor-geoipdb but is not going to be installed; Recommends torsocks but is not going to be installed. I bought the pi 3 with the intent of running either a relay or bridge - I was told that could be done - sigh Adriann 
I am assuming the above is because the tor package simply isn't there.